# Joining Result Sets from Two Unions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have a third party application that generates data into a number of separate tables based on the release. The data format remains consistent, so unions can be performed on the different types of tables.

I would like to include fields from the two unions in one resulting dataset.

The first union is an list of equipment used and is produced using the following statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM PMT_EQUIPMENT_USED_OLD
    UNION
  SELECT * FROM PMT_EQUIPMENT_USED_X
    ) AS U
WHERE U.GRID_EQUIPMENT_ID IS NOT NULL AND U.APP_STATUS <> 'CANCELLED' ORDER  BY U.APP_NUMBER, U.ROW
```

There can be multiple table entries for each piece of equipment in this table.

Here is the table structure:

```
Field,Type,Null,Key,Default
APP_UID,varchar(32),NO,PRI,null
APP_NUMBER,int(11),NO,,null
APP_STATUS,varchar(10),NO,,null
ROW,int(11),NO,PRI,null
GRID_EQUIPMENT_ID,int(11),YES,,null
GRID_EQUIPMENT_ID_LABEL,varchar(64),YES,,null
```

The second union is an inventory report produced using the following statement:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM PMT_RPT_OLD
    UNION
  SELECT * FROM PMT_RPT_X
    ) AS A
ORDER BY A.APP_NUMBER
```

Here is the table structure:

```
Field,Type,Null,Key,Default
APP_UID,varchar(32),NO,PRI,null
APP_NUMBER,int(11),NO,,null
APP_STATUS,varchar(10),NO,,null
PROJECT_TITLE,varchar(255),YES,,null
PROJECT_CHARTER_NUMBER,varchar(32),YES,,null
COMPANY_CITY,varchar(32),YES,,null
COMPANY_COUNTRY,varchar(32),YES,,null
COMPANY_NAME,varchar(255),YES,,null
PROJECT_CHARTER_CLIENT_TYPE_LABEL,varchar(32),YES,,null
PROJECT_CHARTER_CLIENT_SECTOR_OTHER,varchar(255),YES,,null
PROJECT_CHARTER_CLIENT_SECTOR_LABEL,varchar(32),YES,,null
PROJECT_CHARTER_START_DATE,varchar(10),YES,,null
REQUEST_DATE,varchar(10),YES,,null
INQUIRY_DIV,varchar(32),YES,,null
CLIENT_CALLBACK_EXPLAIN,varchar(255),YES,,null
CLIENT_CALLBACK_LABEL,varchar(32),YES,,null
CLIENT_SURVEY_LABEL,varchar(32),YES,,null
PROJECT_CLOSEOUT_FEEDBACK_LABEL,varchar(32),YES,,null
PROJECT_CLOSEOUT_SURVEY_COMMENTS,varchar(255),YES,,null
PROJECT_COMPLETION_SIGNOFF_COMMENTS_PM,varchar(255),YES,,null
PROJECT_LOST_SIGNOFF_COMMENTS_PM,varchar(255),YES,,null
```

I would like to include fields from the report table in the equipment list where the **APP_UID** is identical.

Here's the challenge: the data is constantly being updated and I am passing the query to a reporting tool, so I'm limited to a single statement.

Is there a way to combine the two sets of tables and join them using one statement? If not, is there an alternative approach that I should consider?

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show table structure for the tables involved in the two queries?  By the way, you can drop the subqueries and instead just `UNION` together the two select statements at the same level.  This should also speed up things considerably.

Comment: which column that makes this 2 tables links to each other?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Updated to include table structures generated using DESCRIBE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's a way to join 2 union select statements using mysql

Just like a normal join

**Example :**

```
Select * from tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1.linkcolumn = tbl2.linkcolumn
```

Just simply replace tbl1/tbl2 to your Select union statement and add an alias to it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   pmt_equipment_used_old 
                UNION 
                SELECT * 
                FROM   pmt_equipment_used_x) AS U 
        WHERE  U.grid_equipment_id IS NOT NULL 
               AND U.app_status <> 'CANCELLED' 
        ORDER  BY U.app_number, 
                  U.row) AS TBL1 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
             FROM   (SELECT * 
                     FROM   pmt_rpt_old 
                     UNION 
                     SELECT * 
                     FROM   pmt_rpt_x) AS A 
             ORDER  BY A.app_number) AS TBL2 
         ON TBL1.app_uid = TBL2.app_uid
```

> Also there's no need to wrap your union into a subquery since this 2 select statement which is union have same table columns.
>
> Put your `ORDER BY` after the JOIN statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   pmt_equipment_used_old 
                UNION 
        SELECT * 
                FROM   pmt_equipment_used_x
        WHERE  grid_equipment_id IS NOT NULL 
               AND app_status <> 'CANCELLED') 
               AS TBL1 
       JOIN (SELECT * 
                     FROM   pmt_rpt_old 
                     UNION 
             SELECT * 
                     FROM   pmt_rpt_x
             ORDER  BY app_number) AS TBL2 
         ON TBL1.app_uid = TBL2.app_uid 
         ORDER BY TBL1.app_number, TBL1.row
```

Comment: I don't think you need to wrap the `UNION` queries in subqueries.

Comment: I never heard of ordering two sides of a join, rather the result set should be ordered afterward.  And the same holds true for ordering two parts of a union.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry my mistake.

Comment: I agree with your general idea, but I didn't post because the OP was unclear without seeing at least the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Given the table structures, the resulting statement should then be simplified (and optimized) by eliminating the unnecessary subsqueries and then ordering the result set as opposed to following each query?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your second query is functionally identical to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM PMT_RPT_OLD
UNION
SELECT * FROM PMT_RPT_X
ORDER BY APP_NUMBER
```

Comment: While I agree with you, this isn't a full answer, which isn't even possible because the OP omitted table structure.